# 2-way SSL Certificate Installation in Java

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, keystore

This is the first time am working in ssl. I've done below steps

1. Generated selftsigned certificate " **keytool -genkey -keysize 2048 -keyalg RSA -alias test -keystore Testkeystore** "
2. Generated CSR with "**keytool -certreq -alias test -file Test.csr -keystore Testkeystore**" And i shared **Test.csr** with 3rd party organization and i've recieved two files **Test.p7b** also **client.cer** from them.

am stuck here. ihave no idea what to do next with these to Test.p7b,client.cer . Please help me.

Comment: Some clarifications would be useful in order to provide a useful answer.  Are you managing the server, or are you managing the client?  Is the '3rd party organization' a certificating authority, or are they the people at the other end of your connection?  Do you just need to understand how to install the certificate issued by the certificating authority, or do you need to set up client authentication on your server?

Comment: Our app need to act as server and client,Here we have 2 cases.
 case 1(client):We have application that will send request to '3rd party organization' and they will give just acknowledgement. case2(server):  same app will be listening on specific port ,after some time '3rd party organization' initiate transaction to send result For the same request that i've sent. And '3rd party organization' is the certificating authority . So now i need to setup this.i"ve no idea how to proceed further please suggest me

Comment: You will need to convert the .p7b file to x509 format; see https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html for instructions.  You can then cut the resulting file into separate files for each certificate, and install them in your key store; you can use the instructions at https://blogs.oracle.com/blogbypuneeth/entry/steps_to_create_a_csr step 5.  Finally, you'll need to install the `client.cer` file, assuming it's their machine's certificate, in your key store using `keytool -import -alias client -file client.cer -keystore Testkeystore -v`.

Comment: Hi Warren,I've followed the above steps and i added below lines in my code.
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","Testkeystore");
 System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","*****");

I Got javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed 
I have tried this to solve the above error http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/ . But Iam getting javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure .Please help me.

Comment: Warren I've enable the tcpdump to check whats happening at network level . 1. Client Sent Hello To Server 
        2. Server Sent Hello and Certificate
        3. After this client is not sending certificate to server .At this point i got javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure . Server is sending the certificate which i have imported into my Testkeystore in last step .that is client.cer.

Comment: I think maybe you also need `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "Testkeystore");` so your app will see that the certificate you added is trusted.

Comment: after adding the above line also getting same error.

Comment: I've enabled the System.setProperty("javax.net.debug","all");pool-1-thread-1, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
 pool-1-thread-1, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
 %% Invalidated:  [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA]
 pool-1-thread-1, called closeSocket()
 pool-1-thread-1, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
 pool-1-thread-1, called close()
 pool-1-thread-1, called closeInternal(true)
 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure